# The PATCH method is not supported for this route. when second form is submitted

Tags: laravel, forms

I've been working on a CMS system for a website im building and it all went good untill I added 2 forms on the same page (both updating different things) and yet it still gives me the error in the title while the other form works fine?

The page banner is the one which returns the error and the 'normal' update works fine!

Web.php

```
Route::patch('/beheer/paginas/{product}', 'PageController@update')->middleware('auth')->name('beheer.pages.update');
Route::patch('/beheer/paginas/update-banner/{product}', 'PageController@update-banner')->middleware('auth')->name('beheer.pages.banner.update');
```

Also shows in php artisan route:list that it's a PATCH method route.

My view:

```
@extends('layouts.beheer')

@section('content')
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-header">
                        <div class="d-inline card-title">Pagina bewerken</div>
                        @if ($errors->any())
                            <div class="alert alert-danger">
                                <ul>
                                    @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                                        <li>{{ $error }}</li>
                                    @endforeach
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        @endif
                    </div>

                    <div class="card-body">
                        <form action="{{ route('beheer.pages.update', $page->id) }}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                            @csrf
                            {{ method_field('PATCH') }}
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label>Zichtbaarheid:</label>
                                <select class="custom-select" name="page_hidden">
                                    <option value="0" @if (!$page->page_hidden) selected @endif>Zichtbaar</option>
                                    <option value="1" @if ($page->page_hidden) selected @endif>Verborgen</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label>Pagina naam:</label>
                                <input type="text" name="page_name" value="{{ $page->page_name ? $page->page_name : old('page_name') }}" class="form-control" placeholder="Pagina naam">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label>Pagina tekst:</label>
                                <textarea name="page_text" class="form-control">{{ $page->page_text ? $page->page_text : old('page_meta_title') }}</textarea>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label>Pagina title SEO:</label>
                                <input type="text" name="page_meta_title" value="{{ $page->page_meta_title ? $page->page_meta_title : old('page_meta_title') }}" class="form-control" placeholder="Pagina titel SEO">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label>Pagina beschijving SEO:</label>
                                <input type="text" name="page_meta_description" value="{{ $page->page_meta_description ? $page->page_meta_description : old('page_meta_description') }}" class="form-control" placeholder="Pagina beschijving SEO">
                            </div>
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary float-right">Opslaan</button>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-header">
                        <div class="d-inline card-title">Banner</div>
                        @if ($errors->any())
                            <div class="alert alert-danger">
                                <ul>
                                    @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                                        <li>{{ $error }}</li>
                                    @endforeach
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        @endif
                    </div>

                    <div class="card-body">
                        <form onsubmit="{{ route('beheer.pages.banner.update', $page->id) }}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                            @csrf
                            {{ method_field('PATCH') }}
                            <input type="hidden" name="image_section_banner" value="1">
                            <input type="hidden" name="page_id" value="{{ $page->id }}">

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <img src="{{ asset($page_banner ? $page_banner->image_large_url : asset('assets/img/banner-home.jpg')) }}" class="img-fluid" style="max-height:250px;">
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label>Afbeelding:</label>
                                <input type="file" name="image" value="{{ old('image') }}" class="form-control">
                            </div>
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary float-right">Opslaan</button>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
@endsection
```

If there is any additional information needed please let me know!

Answer (score 1):

There is an attribute missing on your 2nd `<form>`. Here is what you have:

```xml
<form onsubmit="{{ route('beheer.pages.banner.update', $page->id) }}" ...>
```

But it **should** look like this:

```xml
<form action="{{ route('beheer.pages.banner.update', $page->id) }}" ...>
```

Since you did not specify an `action` attribute, it is submitting to the current url which probably doesn't have a `patch` route defined.

Comment: Woow thanks mate been staring at my code for like 2 hours :)